# PHP openssl_public_encrypt "key parameter is not a valid key"

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, warnings, rsa

I have this RSA public key:

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtixUGzGpLXgZ7AV1HfmIHV/FEF+fww77FekRc2oLhUOd4HitwCPo76fjtdsQBEt8w9HZ3CXVphaAU2BA6MEZJ3ShVMsdAXb2ZA1C+lu7k1GV9M/BhucTg35HujSK647Sc5MwVLwFsN80dAnGsZF8gwb2TNUzXHwzbAb30T01zuqf8RCM75OwKZFYqzu7FOVrtk/w9mh92MOXG0l7WSqNIctu8Kxka/tEJJIA5nqMGNMocjwprXy66NS7FFy1GY+NnxfFLtODqq0tllc50UCDsnqSvNmj2wcnAcsCzNOoxPPgp7t8S+sQvOzgc5W3CDjIsYEiGD+vzSVNkGiRou577wIDAQAB
```

(Every other key I try gives the same error, too)

and this string:

```
$str = "VOTE\n" .
"server-list\n" .
"$user\n" .
"$userip\n" .
time()."\n";
```

I use this code to make the string become exactly 256 bytes so that it follows the standard for this specific application:

```
$leftover = (256 - strlen($str)) / 2;
while ($leftover > 0) {
    $str .= "\x0";
    $leftover--;
}
```

To format the key, I do this:

```
    $key = wordwrap($key, 65, "\n", true);
    $key = <<<EOF
    -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
    $key
    -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
EOF;
```

When I do `openssl_public_encrypt($str, $encrypted, $key);` I get the following warning:

`Warning:  openssl_public_encrypt() function.openssl-public-encrypt: key parameter is not a valid public key in ...`

I'm not sure why this is happening. This is what the key looks like when I echo it:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtixUGzGpLXgZ7AV1HfmIH
V/FEF
fww77FekRc2oLhUOd4HitwCPo76fjtdsQBEt8w9HZ3CXVphaAU2BA6MEZJ3ShVMsd
AXb2ZA1C
lu7k1GV9M/BhucTg35HujSK647Sc5MwVLwFsN80dAnGsZF8gwb2TNUzXHwzbAb30T
01zuqf8RCM75OwKZFYqzu7FOVrtk/w9mh92MOXG0l7WSqNIctu8Kxka/tEJJIA5nq
MGNMocjwprXy66NS7FFy1GY
NnxfFLtODqq0tllc50UCDsnqSvNmj2wcnAcsCzNOoxPPgp7t8S
sQvOzgc5W3CDjIsYEiGD vzSVNkGiRou577wIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:
A working key should look like this:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAmHzD76i8DA25nC+Qsswi
OM0lW+gViiQD4tEm7suxBc2BGibtdlrsprVIId92hSjQKx4x8+XVWU6k89T5vy8Y
txpXN759OWdGkDi8uvZuYclMjW9Rao+oqSvbXH37R7oSY287I+6uOHclGhniQN3q
RyoXBkbhDk0/FTI/i549q/gGk1UZYv449KLrDOqmtohRcIyAYVnvvWtD1kIzourq
hMtEIrPqwoBqTaUA9kOIXw1jMovao2TN52j48KgOg9KjqtdwUwD9e6n7hJd/subF
6woc8L7zjJFOHH5gacUC7vtiMpBpnSyLQpjFLepYYwftjsRmg4xLdh+Zvgw3xqi4
lwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: What happened to the `+` signs in your key? They're gone in the formatted block.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure. And I really don't know if they're supposed to be there because I quite frankly don't know what I'm doing. I'm trying to work with the protocol of this: https://github.com/vexsoftware/votifier

Comment: The + signs are representing bytes as much as all the other characters. Base64 encoding uses `A-Ba-b0-9` and `/` & `+` to encode bytes, and possibly the `=` character for padding the last part.

Comment: It's probably the `wordwrap` function, it seems aimed at splitting strings on word boundaries. You are better off just counting characters and inserting the newline characters (**both** of them if I'm not mistaken) manually.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. o3o

Comment: @DrAgonmoray you don't know how to split/combine strings? Maybe it is time for some tutorials?

Comment: @owlstead I really wasn't sure what you're talking about >.>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It occured to me why it wasn't working, so I am here to answer my own question. Now that I think about it, it ties into what @sarnold originally said: the + signs are gone (and they got replaced by spaces)

it turns out that because i was getting the key via HTTP POST, it formatted the URL (and thus the key) turning all the + signs into spaces. That threw off the key and caused this conundrum.

Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 2):

First, I would recommend using phpseclib, a pure PHP RSA implementation.  It's a ton more portable and easier to use and all that jazz.  Example:

```
<?php
$key = 'MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtixUGzGpLXgZ7AV1HfmIHV/FEF+fww77FekRc2oLhUOd4HitwCPo76fjtdsQBEt8w9HZ3CXVphaAU2BA6MEZJ3ShVMsdAXb2ZA1C+lu7k1GV9M/BhucTg35HujSK647Sc5MwVLwFsN80dAnGsZF8gwb2TNUzXHwzbAb30T01zuqf8RCM75OwKZFYqzu7FOVrtk/w9mh92MOXG0l7WSqNIctu8Kxka/tEJJIA5nqMGNMocjwprXy66NS7FFy1GY+NnxfFLtODqq0tllc50UCDsnqSvNmj2wcnAcsCzNOoxPPgp7t8S+sQvOzgc5W3CDjIsYEiGD+vzSVNkGiRou577wIDAQAB';

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey($key);
$rsa->setPublicKey($key);

echo $rsa->getPublicKey();
```

If you insist on using the openssl extension...  try this:

```
"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n" . chunk_split($whatever) . "\r\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `str_replace(' ', '+', $string)`

Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error in PHP (Laravel Framework) by putting the -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- in first code and putting the     -----END PUBLIC KEY----- in last line, the problem was solved

correct syntax

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
$key
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using

> openssl_public_encrypt()

Ensure that no spaces in between the key. Adding **'+'** to eliminate the white spaces ain't recommended as it might change the key-value and lead to the error openssl_public_encrypt(): key parameter is not a valid public key.

I had this issue and my issue was that I had done some code editing which in return added some white spaces in the key. After long attempts and much googling, I generated a new key and maintained it the same without changing or editing the white space and it finally worked.

Hope it helps. openssl is so picky from the few articles I have read. So be carefull not to alter anything in the key as it might be the source of your headaches.

Answer (score 0):

```
function encrypt($data, $pubkey)
{
    $pubkey = openssl_get_publickey($pubkey);

    if (openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encrypted, $pubkey))
    {
        $data = base64_encode($encrypted);
    }
    else
        throw new Exception('Unable to encrypt data. Perhaps it is bigger than the key size?');

    return $data;
}
```

Where public key format like this:

```
$PUBLIC_KEY  = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqG....LosgV4t08P0wIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
$token = encrypt($words, ($PUBLIC_KEY))
```

;